# understand how a gitlab ci pipline works with dind and docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Good morning;
I am new to using gitalb ci.

I wanted to launch a pipline that executes a docker compose , below is the ymal file code, it works

when i read the documentation i find this kind of ymal file
image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest

```
services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker-compose --version

build image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose build
```

I don't understand, if we launch the docker compose build in a dind service, the cluster will launch in the dnd container not in the host server as desired?
why they do that, to do a test ok, it's normal to run the cluster in a container, on the other hand for a deploy it's illogical, how can I use dind but to launch the cluster on the host server itself "on a remote system" ?
THANKS

Comment: It looks like you're running the docker commands on a remote system over ssh, in which case the `docker:dind` service has no effect because you're not running any docker containers within your job environment.

Comment: What sytech wrote. And for your _", no?"_ question, the answer is: Yes, _if_ then only for the dind service. A more detailed answer would require sharing the gitlab runner configuration you ask about.

Comment: @hakre, Thank you for your answer,
I edited my question to make it more clear.
Thanks again.

Comment: @ensberg: For the question you ask it is effectively important which gitlab runner configuration you have. please share it with your question as well.